# Auto tagging Rspec tests with js: true and sauce: true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, phantomjs, saucelabs

I would like all of my describe blocks in the features directory (or alternatively all tests when a certain Capybara driver/env variable is set) to be tagged with `js: true` and `sauce: true` automatically. What is the most clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way you have to clone the rspec gem you are using and then look for the template it uses to generate the spec files and change it.